# How to compare and push field to sub array in object

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have an object which contain name and id. Second object has some fields and that id field from first object.

**For Example:**

```
FirstObj = [{
  _id: '48765465f42424',
  Name : 'Sample'
},{
  _id: '48765465f654654',
  Name : 'Sample1'
}]
secondObj = [{
  Field1 : 5464,
  subarray : [{
        Field2 : 14654,
        Field3 : { IsActive : true,
                     FirstObjid : '48765465f42424'
                  },
        Field4 : { IsActive : true,
                     FirstObjid : '48765465f654654'
                  }
            }]
    },
    {
  Field1 : 2145,
  subarray : [{
        Field2 : 544644,
        Field3 : { IsActive : true,
                     FirstObjid : '48765465f654654'
                  },
        Field4 : { IsActive : true,
                     FirstObjid : '48765465f42424'
                  },
        }]
    }]
```

Now I need to compare both and push that name from `first object` to `secondobj's subobj` beside `FirstObjid` field .

**Expected Output is :**

```
 secondObj = [{
  Field1 : 5464,
  subarray : [{
        Field2 : 14654,
        Field3 : { IsActive : true,
                     FirstObjid : '48765465f42424',
                    Name : 'Sample'
                  },
        Field4 : { IsActive : true,
                     FirstObjid : '48765465f654654',
                    Name : 'Sample1'
                  }
            }]
    },
    {
  Field1 : 2145,
  subarray : [{
        Field2 : 544644,
        Field3 : { IsActive : true,
                     FirstObjid : '48765465f654654',
                     Name : 'Sample1'
                  },
        Field4 : { IsActive : true,
                     FirstObjid : '48765465f42424',
                    Name : 'Sample'
                  },
        }]
    }]
```

How can I achieve it.

Comment: What have you tried? Do you need it in JS or C# (you tagged both)?

Comment: I tried to map function but here it is in sub. I need in JS not C#

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `map` function and compare the object ids like this

```js
var secondObj =  [{
  Field1 : 5464,
  subarray : [{
        Field2 : 14654,
        Field3 : 'sfsadf',
        FirstObjid : '48765465f42424'
        }]
    },
    {
  Field1 : 2145,
  subarray : [{
        Field2 : 544644,
        Field3 : 'awrfsa',
        FirstObjid : '48765465f654654'
        }]
    }]
    
 var FirstObj = [{
  _id: '48765465f42424',
  Name : 'Sample'
},{
  _id: '48765465f654654',
  Name : 'Sample1'
}]

secondObj.subarray = secondObj.map(o => o.subarray.map(k=> FirstObj.map(l=> { 
  if(l._id == k.FirstObjid){
     k.Name = l.Name
  }
  return o;
})))
 

console.log(secondObj)
```

Comment: it would return remapped `subarray` so you might want to `secondObj.subarray = ...`

Comment: @sachilaranawaka Please check the edited question.Ihave multiple arrays  here it is not working

Comment: @charan tej check it again

Comment: @sachilaranawaka the results are mismatched showing the `name` as `sample1` for both and it is placing outside of subarray

Comment: @charan tej my bad. check again

Comment: @sachilaranawaka It worked well but my bad, the mapping should do inside subarray which is in array to map.Please check the edited question.

Answer (score 4):

Try this

```
secondObj.subarray.forEach(function(item){
if(item.FirstObjid==FirstObj._id)
    item.Name = FirstObj.Name
})
```

Comment: Sorry please see the edited question i have multiple arrays in object. Here how to check for each array