# How to map and calculate

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have two objects like below

```
DistanceMatrix = [{
    MaterialId : "AB",
    BeltId : "Belt1",
    Distance : 200
}, {
    MaterialId : "CD",
    BeltId : "Belt2",
    Distance : 220
}]

UnitMatrix = [{
    UnitDistance : 100,
    MaterialMapping :[{
        MaterialId : "AB",
        MaterialName : "name2"
        BeltId : "Belt1"                  
    }, {
        MaterialId : "CD",
        MaterialName : "name2"
        BeltId : "Belt2"                  
    }]
}]
```

Now I want to check **UnitMatrix's** `"MaterialId"` and `"BeltId"` and sum up the **DistanceMatrix's** `"Distance"` with **UnitMatrix's** `"UnitDistance"` and save it to another object with material name.

Expected Result:

```
Total Distance = [{
    Distance_AB : 300
    Distance_CD : 320
}]
```

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Can you show us what you've tried so far?

Comment: Is Unitmatrix array or object

Comment: @JinsPeter it is object

Comment: @rrd I have tried to use this solution before for fetching Distance but here I am mapping checking only one field http://stackoverflow.com/a/43756107/5756149

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your answer

```
 DistanceMatrix = [{
                        MaterialId : "AB",
                        BeltId : "Belt1",
                        Distance : 200
                        },
                       {
                        MaterialId : "CD",
                        BeltId : "Belt2",
                        Distance : 220
                        }]
    UnitMatrix = {
             UnitDistance : 100,
             MaterialMapping :[{
                                MaterialId : "AB",
                                MaterialName : "name2",
                                BeltId : "Belt1"                  
                                },
                                {
                                MaterialId : "CD",
                                MaterialName : "name2",
                                BeltId : "Belt2"                  
                              }]
                 }
var TotalDistance = {};
DistanceMatrix.forEach(function(belt){
       var matchedItem = UnitMatrix.MaterialMapping.filter(function(item){
          return item.MaterialId == belt.MaterialId && item.BeltId ===belt.BeltId;
     })[0];

     if(matchedItem){
        TotalDistance['Distance_'+ belt.MaterialId] = UnitMatrix.UnitDistance+belt.Distance;
     }
});
 console.log(TotalDistance);
```

Comment: In ***matchedItem*** `UnitMatrix distance` directly u wrote but it It is also an object I wrote [0] element but can contain many

Comment: I did ask you if the unitMatrix is an array or an object.?? Do you need another answer where unitMatrix can contain many objects where, we need to select that object containing the material ID?

Comment: Thanks for answering. I have used this function while looping Unitmatrix so I placed Unitmatrix[i] satisfied my problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code to get expected result.

```js
DistanceMatrix = [{
                    MaterialId : "AB",
                    Distance : 200
                    },
                   {
                    MaterialId : "CD",
                    Distance : 220
                  }];
UnitMatrix = [{
         UnitDistance : 100,
            }];
newMatrix = [{}];
for(var i=0;i<DistanceMatrix.length;i++){
  var test = "Distance_"+DistanceMatrix[i].MaterialId;
  newMatrix[0][test] = parseInt(DistanceMatrix[i].Distance) + parseInt( UnitMatrix[0].UnitDistance);;
}

console.log(newMatrix);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use [`Map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) with `DistanceMatrix` and iterate `UnitMatrix` and get the values in objects for the result.

```js
var DistanceMatrix = [{ MaterialId: "AB", BeltId: "Belt1", Distance: 200 }, { MaterialId: "CD", BeltId: "Belt2", Distance: 220 }],
    UnitMatrix = [{ UnitDistance: 100, MaterialMapping: [{ MaterialId: "AB", MaterialName: "name2", BeltId: "Belt1" }, { MaterialId: "CD", MaterialName: "name2", BeltId: "Belt2" }] }],
    getKey = o => [o.MaterialId, o.BeltId].join('|'),
    distance = new Map(DistanceMatrix.map(m => [getKey(m), m])),
    result = UnitMatrix.map(u =>
        Object.assign(...u.MaterialMapping.map(m => 
            ({ ['Distance_' +m.MaterialId]: u.UnitDistance + distance.get(getKey(m)).Distance }))
        )
    );

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

ES5 with an object as hash table instead of a `Map`.

```js
var DistanceMatrix = [{ MaterialId: "AB", BeltId: "Belt1", Distance: 200 }, { MaterialId: "CD", BeltId: "Belt2", Distance: 220 }],
    UnitMatrix = [{ UnitDistance: 100, MaterialMapping: [{ MaterialId: "AB", MaterialName: "name2", BeltId: "Belt1" }, { MaterialId: "CD", MaterialName: "name2", BeltId: "Belt2" }] }],
    getKey = function (o) { return [o.MaterialId, o.BeltId].join('|') },
    distance = DistanceMatrix.reduce(function (r, o) {
        r[getKey(o)] = o;
        return r;
    }, Object.create(null)),
    result = UnitMatrix.map(function (u) {
        var temp = {};
        u.MaterialMapping.forEach(function (m) {
            temp['Distance_' + m.MaterialId] = u.UnitDistance + distance[getKey(m)].Distance;
        });
        return temp;
    });

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: Not running in IE

Comment: @charantej, now the second approach should work for IE.

Answer (score 0):

Try this -

```
DistanceMatrix.map(
  ({MaterialId, Distance})=>({
    [`Distance_${MaterialId}`] : UnitMatrix.Distance + Distance
  })
).reduce((p,v)=>Object.assign({}, p, v), {});
```